# Can't add any PPA's after reinstalling Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, repository

I can't add any PPA's at all after reinstalling Ubuntu 13.10.

Here is what it says:

```
michael@MikesKomputer:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:atareao/atareao'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

This repository is working as far as I know. The problem is that I can't add any new repositories. Even if I can use the Software Center, I can't have my system with the `add-apt-repository` command broken.

Comment: Well I already installed grive.  The problem is that I can't add any new repositories.  Even if I can use Software Center I can't have my system without add-apt-repository broken.

Comment: Sure, but grive is on the default repositories.  I need to be able to install other repositories.

Comment: I can add repositories using System Settings->Software & Updates-> Other Software.  But I need command line to work as well.

Comment: Yes, Python3 does appear to be installed.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that this is a reinstallation of Ubuntu, to fix a boot problem... Maybe something was broken in the process

Answer (score 3):

Long story but this bug was the result of trying to set up a dual boot with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10.

After doing an install with a format of hard drive it works again.

Comment: Is there a bug already reported on this issue? How did you conclude that its a dual boot issue and can be fixed by fomatting? I'm getting the same error, but no fix yet.. I'm manually adding the ppa to the sources list

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Although System wide and apt-conf proxy settings are fine, command with proxy settings solve the problem.

```
sudo https_proxy='https://user:pass@proxy_server:proxy_port/' http_proxy='http://user:pass@proxy_server:proxy_port/' add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

Both proxy definitions should be present since secure and unsecured connection are used in combination through the execution of repository add.