# Cannot add any PPA

Tags: ppa

I recently tried to add PPA from [this website](https://launchpad.net/~jerzy-kozera/+archive/zeal-ppa). 
I did `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper` from terminal. 
I get an error saying

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

As suggested in other similar questions, I don't have any problem with internet connection because `apt-get install` is working as expected. This is not even PPA specific problem, I couldn't add other PPAs as well.  [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364690/cant-add-any-ppas-after-reinstalling-ubuntu-13-10) says that I have to format the entire hard drive to solve this. I definitely cannot do that. Is this bug still unsolved?

I added the PPA line using Software Center. When it updates cache, it comes up with an error saying

```
W:GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net saucy Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F141B5F0C7122F9B, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release i386 (20130424)/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release i386 (20130424)/dists/raring/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Output of `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper`

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

How to solve this and what is the cause of this problem?

Thanks in advance.

OS: Ubuntu 13.10

AFTER EDIT: Before the edit, the question had PPA of Ubuntu SDK.After posting this, I realised that Ubuntu SDK is in the repositories of Ubuntu 13.10. Just thought, may be that's why I cannot add PPA. I tried next PPA and I came up with the same series of errors.

Comment: Ok, run the following `sudo add-apt-repository -m ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa`, copy all the output and edit your question.

Comment: Even with the -m flag, I get the same error as posted in question. "Cannot add PPA....".

Comment: The `-m` flag is not to fix the error... is to debug the error. Copy and paste the output in your question....

Comment: [Here at the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/en/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html) `-m` is not defined. In 14.04 manpage it stands for `massive-debug`.

Comment: @souravc `man add-apt-repository` indeed shows -m as printing a lot of debug information to the command line.

Comment: Precede your PPA with "http://" `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:http://ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa`

Comment: Same error even with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:http://ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa `

Comment: @nitish Path to PPA: http://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-sdk-team, also add https://launchpad.net/~canonical-qt5-edgers/+archive/qt5-proper

Comment: Now, I can download Ubuntu SDK through repositories in Ubuntu 13.10 without adding any PPA. But, I cannot add any PPA. That's why I changed entire question

Answer (score 2):

In addition to configuring proxies, tell sudo to consider the environment with the flag `-E`

```
export http_proxy=http://<proxy>:<port>
export https_proxy=http://<proxy>:<port>
sudo -E apt-add-repository ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper
```

with username and password:

```
export https_proxy=<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>
```

Comment: it worked for me thanks. the proxies were configured but sudo was not using them. and the error message was not helping. great answer!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

More info at   http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/fix-cannot-add-ppa-please-check-that.html

Comment: This didn't work